# Display Contact with independent Name Number pair

Tags: ios, swift

I am accessing contacts in my app. The Contact is displaying correctly but it displayed in format

```
-> Aditya

-> Ankur

-> Bhavya

-> Shubham
```

When I click any of name it fetches me that complete contact `CNContact`

The problem lies in where any name has two numbers associated with it.

> I want it to be displayed as

```
-> Aditya - mob number 1

-> Ankur - mob number 1

-> Bhavya - mob number 1

-> Bhavya - mob number 2

-> Shubham - mob number 1
```

In this format every number is displayed and we can choose it freely

Currently I am using code

```
func openContactPicker() {
        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
            contactPicker.delegate = self
            contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

extension ViewController : CNContactPickerDelegate {
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Contact: \(contact)")
    }
}
```

**I know that this I can do this by creating a new View and design it. But can we do this with the help of framework available**

Answer (score 1):

Asking for frameworks/libraries or SDKs is off-topic on StackOverflow.

You should loop through the given contacts and if there is any contacts with more than one phone number create another record for it.

You could have a model for your results like

```
struct ContactModel {
    let name: String
    let number: String
}
```

convert all the responses to that and store it in a `contact: [ContactModel]` array.

then iterate over your CNContacts and create the models

```
let cnContacts = [CNContact]()
var contacts = [ContactModel]()

cnContacts.forEach {
    let name = "\($0.givenName) \($0.familyName)"
    for number in $0.phoneNumbers {
        contacts.append(ContactModel(name: name, number: number.value.stringValue))
    }
}
```

Note: Code was written here and not tested in XCode so may need some tweaks, but the approach should be fine.

Comment: ok, well unfortunately we cannot help you with that. asking for libraries is off-topic. search github and see what you can find. Note: adding libraries will likely add alot more code to your project than writing your own extension for your requirements.